# Azure Web Packs: Why is there a quota on the temporary folder of a web worker?

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment

I just created a proof-of-concept setup for Windows Azure Packs, having a Front End Server, a Publish Server and a Web Worker. There is a simple plan which allows full control over the web sites cloud. In the plans details the "subscription storage space" is set to unlimited.

To proof that the web site and the deployment is working, I created an external git repository where I put a static file and connected the web site with this repository. The static file is served as expected. Then I created an empty MVC 4 project with only one controller and a simple view. I pushed it, synced and the deployment worked as well.

Now the problem comes up: I pushed my original web site which consists of an MVC 3 project and 500 MB of static resources (PDF, Images, ...). I synced again in the web site administration portal and the deployment starts. However, it breaks because there is insufficient disk space. I checked the web worker VM and there is more than 70 GB of space.

I checked the folder quotas on the web worker using Server Manager's File Server Resource Manager and I see a 200 MB quota on C:\inetpub\temp\DWASFiles\Sites* and for every web site in the form of C:\inetpub\temp\DWASFiles\Sites\WEBSITENAME.

Why is there a 200 MB quota, when the storage is unlimited?

I do understand that such an amount of static resource files shouldn't be part of the web site, but instead should be put on a blob storage space. While this is true for Windows Azure, I don't see a storage feature for Windows Azure Web Packs. What are my possibilites?

Answer (score 0):

You could just put it on a UNC share on a shared storage server (e.g. NAS) somewhere and then setup a virtual directory that maps to that UNC path. This way none of that shared content is actually deployed as part of the app and all you do is have a setup task that configures the vdir on your web site during the setup process.

That said, if you really want to deploy the content with the application itself, there appears to be a way to change the quota via the Management Portal for Administrators. [Check out this TechNet article for details](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/LIBRary/dn520907.aspx).

Comment: Yes, but then the whole idea of having web sites managed by Azure doesn't make sense anymore. My website relies on both, the MVC application and the static resources. Why should I manage one half in Azure Web Packs and the other in a different, manual approach? From my point of view the quota doesn't make sense when you are able to specify that the storage space is unlimited.

Comment: Completely understand. Design wise, I think bundling the stuff with the web site is going to hurt you long term, so I was trying to suggest a way to make it work without having to go changing quotas. It's certainly the way you would want to do it if you were deploying to the cloud or, even if app was on-prem, a CDN. Apparently you can change the quota though, so I'll add details to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but as I already mentioned in my question, the "Subscription Storage Space" is already set to unlimited. Moreover I can't find any option that is set to 200 MB. This number just seems random to me.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, not sure what else to suggest. Ultimately think separating the files from the application is the right answer, but understand if you don't want to take that step right now. Hopefully someone else can help out. Good luck!